# Flask server stops after page refresh

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have simple Flask Application with Debugger active on Windows and OpenCV package.
When I run `python app.py` **server started.**
**When I refresh page few times, flask server stops without any visible reason.**

```
(venv) D:\Mega\Dev\Python\Video>python app.py
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 304-998-710
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Sep/2019 10:50:12] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Sep/2019 10:50:12] "GET /video_feed HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Sep/2019 10:50:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Sep/2019 10:50:37] "GET /video_feed HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Sep/2019 10:50:53] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Sep/2019 10:50:53] "GET /video_feed HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Sep/2019 10:51:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Sep/2019 10:51:05] "GET /video_feed HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Sep/2019 10:51:08] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

(venv) D:\Mega\Dev\Python\Video>
```

I'm using logging:

```
from logging import FileHandler, WARNING

app = Flask(__name__)

file_handler = FileHandler('errorlog.txt')
file_handler.setLevel(WARNING)

app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

But errlog.txt file is empty.

How to handle why FLask server is stopping?

Comment: What version of flask are you using?

Comment: Python 3.7.4
Flask 1.1.1

Comment: I see that you are running in `virtual env`, could you try running it normally?

Comment: Outside venv same problem. After two refreshes Flask server stoped. No error or message.

Comment: Problem seems to on Windows only. On Ubuntu it works just fine.
Back to my question. How troubleshoot problems like this. What loogs, tracer and so on I can use to understand Flask server behavior...?